# creating and using a .csv file with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

So I am creating a .csv file and then allowing the user to share it using the UIActivityViewController.

My code to create the csv file will return the NSURL of the file:

```
- (NSURL *)exportToCSV
{
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"results.csv"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath
                                                contents:nil
                                              attributes:nil];
    }

    NSMutableString *contents = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];

    //fill contents with data in csv format
    // ...

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
    [fileHandle writeData:[contents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [fileHandle closeFile];

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
}
```

and then my activity uses that NSURL to initiate the UIActivityViewController:

```
- (IBAction)shareButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSArray *activityItems = @[@"results.csv", [self.object exportToCSV]];
    UIActivityViewController *shareScreen = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

    [self presentViewController:shareScreen animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I select mail an option, the csv file is not attached. it just has the text "results.csv"

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the file? Is it ok? You can open the file on your simulator's folder (`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/...`; you might have to hold the `option` key to see the `Library` folder in your Mac OS X Finder) and confirm that the file is ok. I generally would just save the string using `NSString` instance method `writeToFile`. Eliminates the `NSFileManager` and `NSFileHandle` stuff, too.

Comment: But in answer to your question, the problem would appear to be in your `fileExistsAtPath` line. You appear to be saying "if the documents directory doesn't exist, then create the file". You probably meant `filePath` there, not `docPath`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem would appear to be in your `fileExistsAtPath` line. You appear to be saying "if the documents directory doesn't exist, then create the file". That's certainly not right.

Personally, I'd lose that stuff and change it to be

```
- (NSURL *)exportToCSV
{
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"results.csv"];

    NSMutableString *contents = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];

    //fill contents with data in csv format
    // ...

    NSError *error;

    [contents writeToFile:filePath
               atomically:YES
                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                    error:&error];

    // check for the error

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I want to share my solution of UIActivityViewController and sharing text as a CSV file. This solution works for sharing via Mail and even Save to Dropbox.

```
@IBAction func shareCsv(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Your CSV text
    let str = self.descriptionText.text!
    filename = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("file.csv")

    do {
        try str.writeToFile(filename!, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let fileData = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filename!)

        let objectsToShare = [fileData]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } catch {
        print("cannot write file")
        // failed to write file – bad permissions, bad filename, missing permissions, or more likely it can't be converted to the encoding
    }

}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Can't make it work with Save to Dropbox when using custom UIActivityItemProvider :-(

Comment: What kind of problem do you have?

Comment: Well it doesn't pick up the file when using custom provider. Placeholder item is set to NSURL to file.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me as a Swift 3 version, works as an attachment in Mail and saves in Dropbox.

```
var csvDetailsString = ""

for myObject in myObjectsArray {
    csvDetailsString = csvDetailsString.appending(myObject.someText)
    csvDetailsString = csvDetailsString.appending(",")
    csvDetailsString = csvDetailsString.appending("More Stuff")
    csvDetailsString = csvDetailsString.appending("\n")

}

let fileName = "Output"
let docDirectory = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
if let fileURL = docDirectory?.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("csv") {
    do {
        try csvDetailsString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)

        let objectsToShare = [fileURL]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.addToReadingList]
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```